# how to brighten a specific part of screen in android..?

Tags: android, screen

right now I am using the below code to increase the entire screen brightness form 0 to 89% during runtime...

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp;
Runnable runnable;

lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = 0 / 100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(brightness<90){
                lp.screenBrightness = ++brightness / 100.0f;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

My problem is that I do not want to increase the entire screen brightness, but i wish to increase the brightness of a specific part of the screen.
Is there a way to achieve this...? I have no problem if it is in runtime or if it is static..

Comment: This is not possible. Perhaps you should reevaluate your feature. Because this makes no sense, from the perspective of brightness. However a close alternative would be to have an overlay in your activity that applies alpha to a view that covers part of your screen.

Comment: @JoxTraex Thanks for responding..can you please give me a small example of what you are saying...